# Getting error "Locator must be serializable to JSON using a `toJson` method. By.tagName: Text"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using relative locators using selenium 4.0.0-alpha-6  version.

When I try to read a `<Text>` tag right of  `By.name("User")`.  I am getting the below error.

> Locator must be serializable to JSON using a `toJson` method. By.tagName: Text".

Steps to reproduce:

```
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.withTagName;

public void relativelocator() {

    WebElement element= 
**returnappiumdriver().findElement(withTagName("Text").toRightOf(By.name("User")));**

    System.out.println(" element  "+ element.getAttribute("Name"));
    System.out.println(" element  "+ element.getSize());

    System.out.println(" element  "+ element.getTagName());

    System.out.println(" element  "+ element.getLocation());

    String text = element.getText();

    System.out.println(" text  "+ element.getText());
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Locator must be serializable to JSON using a `toJson` method. By.tagName: Text
    
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.assertLocatorCanBeSerialized(RelativeLocator.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.access$100(RelativeLocator.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator$RelativeBy.<init>(RelativeLocator.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator$RelativeBy.<init>(RelativeLocator.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator$RelativeBy.<init>(RelativeLocator.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.withTagName(RelativeLocator.java:63)
    at com.manh.cp.mobileUI.util.Commonfunctions.testrelativelocator(Commonfunctions.java:989)
    at com.manh.cp.mobileUI.steps.PosStoreUIStepDefinitions.lambda$new$41(PosStoreUIStepDefinitions.java:270)
    at ✽.And Read next element of(Examples/000-Example-scenarios.feature:36
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar file, we will get below error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName

You have to download Selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-4.jar files from the below and clears your issue

https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=4.0-alpha4/